# Coredata: Strategy Pattern Implementation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, strategy-pattern

I'm trying to implement the Strategy pattern using Core Data and Objective C.

To simplify, I have, say, a multilingual `Text` entity, which has several attributes, such as a `Date` for last saved, and a `NSSString` for author etc etc. I want to add a reference to a `Language` entity, which could be one of several subclasses, such as `French`, `Italian` and so on, holding an `NSString` of text in the language of the class name. Each of the `Language` subclasses can implement their own `translateTo` and `translateFrom` methods and the `Text` instance doesn't need to worry about it. Simple Strategy Pattern.

[Created by yuml.me http://yuml.me/1caedd69](http://yuml.me/1caedd69)

I'm really struggling to set up this kind of relationship with Core Data, where a certain `Text` entity can be set up with its own `Language` implementation depending on the details of the instance.

I suppose in a nutshell, what I'm trying to do is create a "has-a" relationship, where the entity inside the `Text` entity can be one of several subtypes of `Language`.

Core Data is quite new to me, so if I'm completely missing the point here, or have missed something glaringly obvious, please let me know.

Comment: btw: what did you use to draw your model? like the "sketchy" feel

Comment: I used http://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy/class/draw - Just Googled for it for this problem - seems quite nice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have abstract entities. I'd create a Language abstract entity, a to-on relatioship between Text and Language, and concrete subentities of Language called Italian, French etc. Example with the Xcode editor:[The Xcode editor showing a diagram much like the one in the original question http://files.droplr.com.s3.amazonaws.com/files/762938/1u3s2W.Screen%20shot%202010-08-05%20at%2010%3A50%3A57.png](http://files.droplr.com.s3.amazonaws.com/files/762938/1u3s2W.Screen%20shot%202010-08-05%20at%2010%3A50%3A57.png)

You would then set the .language relationship of your Text with a new Italian or French `NSManagedObject` as needed.

Comment: Be aware of a potential performance issue with this concept.  Each entity that is a subentity will be placed into a single table.  Therefore in this example, Italian and French would actually live in the same table and potentially creating a lot of void space.

Comment: Thanks - it turns out what I was missing was the designation of the parent on the entity. Doesn't seem so obvious how to do that in the new version of Xcode - back on Xcode 3 and it's all good. Thanks again.